# mask an import by a different name

Tags: python

I am new to python. How can I change the name of installation that is done using pip.
I.e

```
pip3 install requests && echo "done installing"
```

what I want to do is import it under a different name in my script. so instead of `import requests` it would be `import whatevernameiwant`. I run centos if it matters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install python package with a different name using PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308293/how-to-install-python-package-with-a-different-name-using-pip)

Answer (score 2):

`import library_name as my_alias`

eg:

```
import math as maths_is_cool
a = maths_is_cool.sqrt(4)
print(a)
# Prints 2.0
```

This will work for any library, even if it is installed via pip. I reccommend if you are sharing the project, you create a `requirements.txt` file to track the libraries you have installed that your code depends on.

Comment: this is not what I want, instead of `import math as maths_is_cool` I want `import whatevername as maths_is_cool`

Comment: yes, this will work for whatever library you have installed

Comment: @User1984 do you want to change the module name you installed?

Comment: ok I know this, but it is not what I am asking

Comment: Changing the actual import name is impossibe without modifying the library. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817170/7644446) for a similar question